# htaccess rewrite everything with and without question mark

Tags: .htaccess

For years I've been using a few basic lines to rewrite all urls to my router. With the main RewriteRule being:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I now want to extend it with adding everything that comes after the question mark as another wildcard. So that for example /register?username=Marco becomes index.php?page=register&username=Marco and /articles/1/shirt?color=red&size=L becomes index.php?page=articles/1/shirt&color=red&size=L

So far I came up with the following, however that will only match everything behind the question mark and still put it in the page variable.

```
#rewrite problem
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?p=$1&%2 [L]
```

Looking for this online I only found how to either rewrite the query string or everything else, nothing combined. So some help would be welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The moment you come up with the answer to your own question minutes after posting it...

Anyway I came up with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?p=$1 [L]
```